# Why larastan raise errors on array parameter definitions?

Tags: laravel, phpstan

After I set in phpstan.neon parameter :

```
level: 7
```

I got errors :

```
30     Method App\Rules\ItemModelRules::getValidationRulesArray() has parameter $skipFieldsArray with no value type specified in iterable type array.
 See: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-no-value-type-specified-in-iterable-type
30     Method App\Rules\ItemModelRules::getValidationRulesArray() return type has no value type specified in iterable type array.
 See: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-no-value-type-specified-in-iterable-type
61     Method App\Rules\ItemModelRules::getValidationMessagesArray() return type has no value type specified in iterable type array.
 See: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-no-value-type-specified-in-iterable-type
```

On a file with code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Enums\ItemPriority;
use App\Enums\ItemStatus;
use App\Models\Item;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

/*
Class-container for rules/messages of items validation
*
*/

class ItemModelRules
{
    /*
     return validation rules array for item model
     *
      @param int - $itemId - ID of item
      *
      * which fields must be skipped from array
      @param array<string> $skipFieldsArray
      *
      * @returns array<string, string>
      *
    */
    public static function getValidationRulesArray(int $itemId = null, array $skipFieldsArray = []): array  // THAT is where 1st and 2nd errors are pointing
    {
        $itemTable = (new Item)->getTable();
        $validationRulesArray = [
            'parent_id' => 'nullable|exists:' . $itemTable . ',id',
            ...
            'description' => 'string|required',
        ];
        foreach ($skipFieldsArray as $field) {
            if (!empty($validationRulesArray[$field])) {
                $validationRulesArray = Arr::except($validationRulesArray, $field);
            }
        }

        return $validationRulesArray;
    }

    /*
     * Returns custom Messages for validation errors
      *
      * @returns array<string, string>
    */
    public static function getValidationMessagesArray(): array   // THAT is where 3rd errors are pointing
    {
        return [
            'parent_id.invalid' => 'Parent Id is invalid. Must be valid reference to items table',
            'user_id.invalid' => 'User Id is invalid. Must be valid reference to users table',
        ];
    }
}
```

I read refereced help and seems I used proper syntax in methods definition...
How that can be fixed ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.34.2",
"nunomaduro/larastan": "^2.6.4",
```

**FIXED CODE :**

I remade file App\Rules\ItemModelRules like :

```
class ItemModelRules
{

    /*
 * @param int - $itemId - ID of item
 *
 * which fields must be skipped from array
 * @param array<int, string> $skipFieldsArray
 *
 * @return array<string, string>
 *
 */
    public static function getValidationRulesArray(int $itemId = null, array $skipFieldsArray = []): array
    {
        $itemTable = (new Item)->getTable();
        $validationRulesArray = [
            'parent_id' => 'nullable|exists:' . $itemTable . ',id',
            ...
            'description' => 'string|required',
        ];
        foreach ($skipFieldsArray as $field) {
            if ( ! empty($validationRulesArray[$field])) {
                $validationRulesArray = Arr::except($validationRulesArray, $field);
            }
        }

        return $validationRulesArray;
    }

    /*
  * Returns custom Messages for validation errors
  *
  * @return array<string, string>
  */
    public static function getValidationMessagesArray(): array
    {
        return [
            'parent_id.invalid' => 'Parent Id is invalid. Must be valid reference to items table',
            'user_id.invalid' => 'User Id is invalid. Must be valid reference to users table',
        ];
    }
}
```

But anyway I got similar errors pointing at declaration of my methods...

```
Line   ItemModelRules.php
------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
29     Method App\Rules\ItemModelRules::getValidationRulesArray() has parameter $skipFieldsArray with no value type specified in iterable type array.
          See: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-no-value-type-specified-in-iterable-type
  29     Method App\Rules\ItemModelRules::getValidationRulesArray() return type has no value type specified in iterable type array.
          See: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-no-value-type-specified-in-iterable-type
  60     Method App\Rules\ItemModelRules::getValidationMessagesArray() return type has no value type specified in iterable type array.
          See: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-no-value-type-specified-in-iterable-type
Did I miss something ?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` issue is that you are using `@returns` but not `@return`. `@return` is only valid: https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types.

The other error, if I am not confused, is that you did not specify a `key` and `value`, but just `value`.

So, your final PHPDoc should be like this:

```php
/**
 * @param int $itemId ID of item
 * @param array<int, string> $skipFieldsArray which fields must be skipped from array
 *
 * @return array<string, string>
 */

/**
 * Returns custom Messages for validation errors
 *
 * @return array<string, string>
 */
```

Comment: Please read FIXED CODE

Comment: @PetroGromovo I have updated the code, check again (literally copy paste each part, same identation, same characters, same everything)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be that you start your doc blocks with /* instead of /**
If i recall correctly only with a double asterisk it is considerd a valid PHPDoc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).